# How do I parse partial HTML?

Tags: php, html, dom, parsing

I'm trying to parse some HTML with DOM in PHP, but I'm having some problems. First, in case this change the solution, the HTML that I have is not a full page, rather, it's only part of it.

```
<!-- This is the HTML that I have --><a href='/games/'>
<div id='game'>
<img src='http://images.example.com/games.gif' width='300' height='137' border='0'>
<br><b> Game </b>
</div>
<div id='double'>
<img src='http://images.example.com/double.gif' width='300' height='27' border='0' alt='' title=''>
</div>
</a>
```

Now I'm trying to get only the div with the id `double`. I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. What might I be doing wrong?

```
//The HTML has been loaded into the variable $html
$dom=new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$keepme = $dom->getElementById('double'); 

$contents = '<div style="text-align:center">'.$keepme.'</a></div>';
echo $contents;
```

Comment: What is it doing or not doing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think [`DOMDocument::getElementById`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) will not work in your case : *(quoting)*

> For this function to work, you will
>   need either to set some ID attributes
>   with `DOMElement::setIdAttribute` or a
>   DTD which defines an attribute to be
>   of type ID. 
> In the later case, you
>   will need to validate your document
>   with `DOMDocument::validate` or
>   `DOMDocument->validateOnParse` before
>   using this function.

A solution that might work is using some [XPath query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) to extract the element you are looking for.

First of all, let's load the HTML portion, like you first did :

```
$dom=new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

The `var_dump` is here only to prove that the HTML portion has been loaded successfully -- judging from its output, it has.

Then, instanciate the [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/domxpath) class, and use it to query for the element you want to get :

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query("//*[@id = 'double']");
$keepme = $result->item(0);
```

We now have to element you want ;-)

But, in order to inject its HTML content in another HTML segment, we must first get its HTML content.

I don't remember any "easy" way to do that, but something like this sould do the trick :

```
$tempDom = new DOMDocument();
$tempImported = $tempDom->importNode($keepme, true);
$tempDom->appendChild($tempImported);
$newHtml = $tempDom->saveHTML();
var_dump($newHtml);
```

And... We have the HTML content of your `double` `<div>` :

```
string '<div id="double">
<img src="http://images.example.com/double.gif" width="300" height="27" border="0" alt="" title="">
</div>
' (length=125)
```

Now, you just have to do whatever you want with it ;-)

Comment: YES!  I was looking everywhere for how to get a fragment vs. a full HTML doc, and almost gave up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

From [`DomDocument::getElementById`](http://www.php.net/manual/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

> For this function to work, you will
>   need either to set some ID attributes
>   with DOMElement::setIdAttribute  or a
>   DTD which defines an attribute to be
>   of type ID. In the later case, you
>   will need to validate your document
>   with DOMDocument::validate or
>   DOMDocument->validateOnParse before
>   using this function.

For some additional information

- [Simplify PHP DOM XML parsing - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651)
- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

And since someone will mention doing it with a Regular Expression sooner or later, here is the pattern you could use: `/<div id='double'>(.*)<\/div>/simU`

In addition, you could just use regular string functions to extract the div part, e.g.

```
$div = strstr($html, '<div id="double">');
$div = substr($div, 0, strpos($div, '</div>') + 6);
echo $div;
```

While I agree, you should not use RegEx or String functions for *parsing* HTML or XML, I find it absolutely okay to do so, *as long as your only concern is to get this single div* from the fragments. Keep it simple.

Comment: Unless there are nested div tags of course. Regular expressions are *not* for parsing html.

Comment: I would agree if he was actually *parsing* that fragment. but he just wants to extract one clearly defined piece out of it. It's not like he is traversing the DOM, so I guess it's ok to treat the fragment as a string.

Comment: Besides, I already pointed him to SimpleHTML in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Tidy should be capable of "correcting" broken and fragmented HTML documents, turning them into something that can be parsed with other tools

http://devzone.zend.com/article/761

> The Tidy extension is new in PHP 5,
>   and is available from PHP version
>   5.0b3 upward. It is based on the TidyLib library, and allows the
>   developer to validate, repair, and
>   parse HTML, XHTML and XML documents
>   from within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the same question for several hours, I came to this solution which does work for me and is relatively simple compared to what else I found online.

This solution fixes unwanted DOCTYPE and html, body tags as well as encoding issues.

```php
$htmlContent = "<h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p>";

// 1.) Load the html
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='charset=utf-8' /><div>$htmlContent</div>");

// 2.) Do you logic
$dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]->setAttribute('class', 'happy');

// 3.) Render the html
$wrapperNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
$renderedHtml = $dom->saveHTML($wrapperNode);
// If you want to keep the wrapper div
echo $renderedHtml;
// Or remove the wrapper <div>
echo substr(trim($renderedHtml), 5, -6);
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>An XML document can only have one element at the root level. Probably, the HTML parser has a similar requirement. Try wrapping the content in a `<body/>` tag.</strike>

Seems it's something else. [This page](https://fosswiki.liip.ch/display/BLOG/GetElementById+Pitfalls) describes what may be the cause. I'd recommend that you use XPath to get the element.

Answer (score -1):

The fragment is HTML, but to be parsed through DOM it should XHTML.
Every open tag must be closed.

In your case it means you should replace `<br>` with `<br />` and `<img ... >` with `<img ... />`

Comment: That is actually not true. 

$dom->loadHTML("<div><img src='foo' width=150><br></div>") works just fine and doesn't fail parsing. In fact, $dom->saveXML() will show you output with properly closed tags.

Comment: It all depends on the library you use. In python: xml.dom.minidom.parseString("<br>") -> returns an exception. xml.dom.minidom.parseString("<br />") works. I'd prefer to have the input in the correct format in the first place than relying on a library to parse the incorrect input as I expect.